# Target specific href with jQuery

Tags: jquery, click, href

I'm using this code to open multiple links on a page,
http://fiddle.jshell.net/njA8z/1/

But  -- 
1. I want the code to target only hrefs within a div with class links  ---
2. I'll need to re-use same code on another page but to target all links with class links ex.

```
<a href="#!mylink" class="links">Link</a>
```

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using jQuery's [`.hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) method.

Something like this should work

```
if($('div').hasClass('links')){
    // do what you need to with the links in here
}
```

Comment: Thank you. this looks very nice.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
$("div a.links[href]");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$('#ButtonOne').click(function() {
    $('div a.links').each(function() {
        window.open($(this).attr('href'););
    });
});
```